# Add div to JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code below in a JS file and I need to insert this div after the "Artwork" section

```
<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="files">
        <img src="ohtupload.jpg">
    </label>
</div>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is replace the files button with the image-upload div. What's the best way of accomplishing this? Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
,turnaround_time   :{type:"div",title:"Turnaround Time (see <a href='#' class=opens-overlay html-id=pricing >Pricing Table</a>)"}//css:empty shows msg
            ,ship_name         :{type:"text",class:"one-half hide-if-optional",title:"Shipping Info: Name"}//remove repeat references to "Ship" after first
            ,ship_company_name :{type:"text",class:"one-half hide-if-optional never-required",title:"Company Name"}
            ,ship_address      :{type:"text",class:"one-half hide-if-optional",title:"Address"}
            ,ship_city         :{type:"text",class:"one-half hide-if-optional",title:"City"}
            ,ship_state        :{type:"text",class:"one-half hide-if-optional",title:"State"}
            ,ship_zip          :{type:"text",class:"one-half hide-if-optional",title:"Zip",validate:function(val){ return (val+'').trim().match(/^[0-9]{4,}-?[0-9]+$/i)?1:0 }}
            ,group_4:"Artwork"
            ,files             :{type:"file"/*,multiple:true*/, class:"dropzone",custom:function(part){

                part.data("customvalue",[])
                Dropzone.autoDiscover = false
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert the html string into a property as a value?

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and explain your issue in more detail as well as provide a [mcve]

Comment: Correct @Chris that's what Im trying to do

Comment: where and what is the Artwork section?

Comment: It's a file upload section

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but just add it as a string value to a property:

```
turnaround_time.htmldiv = '<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="files">
        <img src="ohtupload.jpg">
    </label>
</div>'
```

Or if you want to hard code it just stick this in there as a property & value right after the *files* property